# woff conversion

Tags: fonts, conversion

I'm having problems with a custom font in Google Chrome and Safari using the WOFF Format.
I Figured out that the look can dramatically change depending on the converter I use (font-squirrel, ...).
I haven't found any converter which would output a clean WOFF file for this font (Gill sans Light).
By "clean" I mean a file in which all letters (including common European accented letters) would be well drawn so that the rendered result would not be smeared.

So where can I find the best converting tool to avoid letters artefacts ? :)

Thank you !
Stev.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this online converter](http://orionevent.comxa.com). It is pretty barebones, so it shouldn’t touch the [font hinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting) like FontSquirrel’s.